# How to stop a react component from rerendering when a redux state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm listening to my redux state using the `useSelector` hook in my functional component. What I'm looking for is to stop the component from rerendering when a certain variable in my state changes. I still want to be able to listen to it, but I don't want to trigger a rerender. So far I've come across answers to avoid useless renders, but I want to stop them completely on that particular variable.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The whole point of *connecting* to Redux is to trigger re-renders when the store changes. You can just import the store object directly rather than connecting the component. That way you have access to it, but changes don't cause re-renders. This is a pretty uncommon use case but sounds like what you're after

Comment: Do you mean unnecessary re-renders when the values do not change in the state?

Comment: If the variable should never trigger a rerender in the component, why do you need it in the component in the first place? It sounds like you're trying to do some logic in a component which belongs somewhere else.

Comment: @Jayce444 this particular variable in my redux store is changed by another component, and I do want to listen to this change in the component I'm talking about. but I don't want it to rerender when it changes because I'm doing animations and it will mess things up. I'm doing the rerendering when another event happens.

Comment: @Zduduu In that case the correct approach here is to control it so that animations only happen when specific values change. Without any specifics or code I can't say what that would involve, but trying to prevent the re-render when the store value changes isn't the correct approach. You always want re-rendering when state/props change or hooks return new values